# Skip saving associated object if invalid on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a person table and address table like this:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  validates :address_line_1, presence: true
end
```

In my controller, I want to update the person and the associated addresses, but if the address is invalid and the person is valid, I'd still want to update the Person object and keep the invalid address the same as before without running into a `ROLLBACK`.

What's the best way to handle this? I realize I can do some logic to check if the address is invalid and remove the `addresses_attributes` from the parameters, then assign the parameters again and save it, but is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

`has_many` association has a `validate` option you can set to false and handle validations however you want https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-validate

I think you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` since you named the `addresses_attributes` param, personally I wouldn't combine no validation with that, you may end up with invalid addresses.

Personally, I would do two step (with the default `validate: true` config):

- first update only the user's attributes
- call save on the user (so addresses doesn't mess the update up)
- set the addresses attributes
- call save on the user (so everything gets validated again)

EDIT: if you want to use the `validate: false` option you may want to set `autosave: false` too so you don't save invalid addresses https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-autosave

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you'll either want to check that the address attributes are valid and remove them if not OR saved the records separately.

A common pattern is to opt for second option using a [form object](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects). This helps keep the logic out of the controller and makes it easier to expand on updating a `Person` in the future.